# Proper Strategy to Fetch Initial Data AngularJS/Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an application the loads a default page, and that default page requires some data to render itself.

In the page, I have a directive that wraps the data with some view elements.  I want the application to fetch data when the directive "loads", so that as soon as the data is returned the directive can start the process of presenting the data (e.g. ng-repeat for some lists, etc.).

What is the best life cycle phase to kick of a call to a REST service to get data (compile, link, postlink)?

Note the REST service is declared in an angular Service object and injected into the controller.

Example:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div my-directive data="{{data}}>
</div>

angular.module('angularTestApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'route/to/my/view/template.html',
            restrict: 'AE',
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                //fetch data here?
                scope.getMyData();  //calls REST service and sets value in the controller and set value for binding
            }
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.doSomething = function () {
                    console.log('I\'m doing something useful');
                }

                //does call to controller to fetch data go here?
                scope.getMyData();  //calls REST service and set value in the controller for binding
            }
        };
    });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('angularTestApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'InjectedService', function ($scope, InjectedService) {
    $scope.data = {};  
    $scope.getData = function() {
       InectedService.get(function(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using isolated scopes on the directive itself and using a resolve inside your `MainCtrl` controller.

If you just end up with `$scope.data` being whatever... just do `$scope.data = InjectedService.get();` in your `MainCtrl` and it should just work.

So long as injected service returns a $q promise, then it will all be automatic. You don't need most of the code you wrote.

In other words, let your controller get the data. Your directive does NOT need to worry about it.

Comment: What would you recommend to do to "kick off" the call to the service?

Comment: Use ng-route's `resolve` or just bind directly to the promise. That will "kick off" the request. In your controller, `$scope.data = service.get();` that's it... don't overthink it!